# How to allow a different singleton class to be instantiated by passing different parameters into the constructor

Tags: c#, design-patterns, singleton

I have a class in my project and I want to instantiate it only once by passing a specific parameter via the constructor, but when I pass different parameter it should instantiate a new one. How I can achieve this with the singleton design pattern? Or can you suggest another design pattern if it can't be achieved with a singleton?

```
class Program
{
static void Main()
{
    SiteStructure s = SiteStructure.Instance;
}
}

public sealed class SiteStructure
{
static readonly SiteStructure _instance = new SiteStructure();
public static SiteStructure Instance
{
    get
    {
        return _instance;
    }
}
SiteStructure()
{
    // Initialize.
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to modify the way the `_instance` variable is initialised, making use of a function that accepts the parameter value that you want to pass in. Also, the `_instance` variable can no longer be `readonly` as it needs to be initialised inside of the new function.

```
[TestMethod]
public void CreateSingletonInstance()
{
    SiteStructure s = SiteStructure.GetInstance("Abc123");
    Debug.Print(s.Parameter); // outputs Abc123

    SiteStructure s2 = SiteStructure.GetInstance("Is it really a singleton?");
    Debug.Print(s2.Parameter); // outputs Is it really a singleton?

    SiteStructure s3 = SiteStructure.GetInstance("Abc123");
    Debug.Print(s3.Parameter); // outputs Abc123

    Assert.AreNotEqual(s, s2); // Check to make sure they are different instances
    Assert.AreEqual(s, s3); // Check to make sure they are the same instance
}

public sealed class SiteStructure
{
    static Dictionary<string, SiteStructure> _siteStructures = new Dictionary<string, SiteStructure>();
    static object _instance_Lock = new object();
    public static SiteStructure GetInstance(string parameter)
    {
        if (!_siteStructures.ContainsKey(parameter))
        {
            lock (_instance_Lock)
            {
                if (!_siteStructures.ContainsKey(parameter))
                {
                    _siteStructures.Add(parameter, new SiteStructure(parameter));
                }
            }
        }

        return _siteStructures[parameter];
    }

    private SiteStructure(string parameter)
    {
        // Initialize.
        Parameter = parameter;
    }

    public string Parameter { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't OP want multiple singletons rather than something that returns a new instance of `SiteStructure` each time the parameter changes? If you do `var a1 = GetInstance("a"); var b = GetInstance("b"); var a2 = GetInstance("a");` then you will end up with 3 instances, not 2.

Comment: @john I see how you edited the question, I didn't read the original version the same way as you. I will update my answer to work with your edit.

Comment: Oh, do you think my edit's wrong? Did I misunderstand?

Comment: @john I read it as (paraphrased) "Singleton, return same class no matter what parameter is passed in", but I can also see how your edits of "return a new Singleton per different parameter, therefore maintain a collection of singletons differing by parameter" could also be valid. Perhaps I should wait for the OP to clarify their question/required direction...

Comment: @john I want to only one instance with parameter "A123" , code should not allow to create instance  with same parameter but yes with different parameter (like 'ABC') it should allow . how i can achieve this ?

Comment: @FrazZaki I have updated my answer. If you pass in "A123" you will get the same instance no matter how many times you call `GetInstance`, if you pass in "ABC", you will get a wholly new instance. The TestMethod at the start of the answer checks to make sure the instances are correct

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace Rextester
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var g = SiteStructure.Instance(4);
        }
    }



    public sealed class SiteStructure { 
 public static SiteStructure Instance() 
 { return new SiteStructure();
 }
        public static SiteStructure Instance (int x)
        { return new SiteStructure (x);
        }

 SiteStructure() { }
SiteStructure(int x) { Console.WriteLine("Hello"); }


}

}
```